# Value after re-test with given reliability

Tags: self-study, reliability

The question is this:
A test results in a z-value of 2, the reliability of the test is 0.9 (and the trait/criterion measured is very stable). The test is done again after some days. Which value is to be expected?

Following answers were given to choose from:
1.8  / 1.5  /  2.0  /  1.0

Can someone explain how to answer this question and what's the calculation/formula?

Edit: now I know more about the context of this question, which is the [Regression Fallacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_fallacy). So I think, the z-value of 2 is considered as an extreme value and in a re-test, the value may be 2.0 * 0.9 = 1.8

Comment: Since this appears to be either homework or self-study, please add the self-study flag.  It alerts us to guide you to the answer, thereby improving your understanding of the underlying thought process, rather than simply provide it to you.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: Thanks you, I added the tag and also some more information.